# go excute http.ListenAndServe("8080",nil) but Process exit

Tags: go

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/user/login", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(writer,"Hello world")
    })
    //启动一个服务器
    http.ListenAndServe("8080",nil)
}
```

[image]

i want to listen 8080 port , but when i run this code , it is exit auto

Comment: `http.ListenAndServe("8080",nil)` returns err. Try to print it to better understand why it is failing, e.g. `fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe("8080",nil))` will print `nil`, if it works fine, else it will print the actual error.

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/):

The correct syntax for `ListenAndServe` is `ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)`

If you add log with `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("8080", nil))`, you could see the error:

> 2020/11/12 14:44:11 listen tcp: address 8080: missing port in address

Answer (score 0):

Your listen port address could be wrong format. below snippet works

```
 package main
    import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
    )
    
    func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", Helloworld)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    }
    
    func Helloworld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
    }
```